# angular.js trying to many iterations when wrapping ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

After following the basic idea of this answer on SO [Angular.js ng-repeat: opening/closing elements after x iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506973/angular-js-ng-repeat-opening-closing-elements-after-x-iterations)

I'm grouping items and wrapping them in a div, and getting the following error `Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:`

This leads me to believe that Angular is expecting 10 repeats and is only registering 5. However, the output looks correct, all 10 items are shown.

I'm building a windows start screen type layout, where some of the tiles will be single, others double width. I'm doing some calculations to wrap the tiles in a div.

The filter I've built is

```
app.filter('partition', function() {
  var part = function(arr, size) {
    if ( 0 === arr.length ) return [];
    var applist=[];
    var partlist=[];
    var blocksize=0;
    console.log(arr);
    for(var a in arr){
        var app = arr[a];

        if(app.width=='single'){
            console.log(app.name);
            partlist.push(app);
            blocksize++;
        }
        if(app.width=='double' && blocksize=4){
            applist.push(partlist);
            partlist=[app];
            blocksize=2;
        }

        if(blocksize==size || a==arr.length-1){
                applist.push(partlist);
                partlist=[];
                blocksize=0;
            }
    }
    console.log(applist)
   return applist;
  };
  return part;
});
```

and the html with the ng-repeats are

```
<div ng-repeat="block in apps | filter:search | partition:6" class="app-block" >
    <li ng-repeat="app in block" class="app-tile" ng-class="{double:app.width=='double'}">
          <div class="name">{{app.name}}</div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Am I using the nested repeats wrong? As I said, the number of tiles being displayed is correct, but the error is what is concerning me (it's big, ugly and red).

Answer (score 4):

The root issue here is that your `partition` filter returns an array of arrays; each digest cycle, it returns a *different* array of arrays, even though the elements *inside* the internal arrays are the same.

For example, check this expression in your JavaScript console:

```javascript
[[1, 2], [3, 4]] == [[1, 2], [3, 4]] // false
```

Because `ngRepeat` thinks the arrays are different each time, it continue re-runs a digest cycle, up until it reaches the maximum of 10.

If you have a Plunker or JSFiddle that provides a more complete, working picture of your problem, that would be helpful in demonstrating a solution; in lieu of that, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16511982/62082) and also the accepted answer on that question.

One thing you can do is manipulate the data in the controller and iterate over that instead:

```javascript
app.controller('SomeController', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.apps = [ ... ];

  var calculateBlocks = function() {
    var filteredBlocks = $filter('filter')($scope.search);
    $scope.appsBlocks = $filter('partition')(filteredBlocks, 6);
  };

  // Every time $scope.apps changes, set $scope.appsBlocks
  // to the filtered and partitioned version of that data.
  // In AngularJS 1.4+ you can use $watchCollection:
  // http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection
  $scope.$watch('apps', calculateBlocks, true);
  // Same if the search term changes.
  $scope.$watch('search', calculateBlocks);
});
```

Then in your HTML:

```html
<div ng-repeat="block in appsBlocks" class="app-block" >
  <li ng-repeat="app in block" class="app-tile" ng-class="{double:app.width=='double'}">
    <div class="name">{{app.name}}</div>
  </li>
</div>
```