# Exclude div from Angular digest

Tags: angularjs

I have a div with a chart that's generated outside of Angular. The div is inside an ng-repeat though, and when the scope is updated, the chart is cleared. Is there a way to prevent the div with the chart from being redrawn?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
    <span>{{ object.title }}</span>
    <div class="chart"></div> <!-- This is being cleared when object changes -->
</div>
```

I looked into using [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce), but my data changes, so I can't (?) use that.

To be clear, all I'm changing is an attribute like `object.title`. I don't expect the chart to stick around if the entire array of objects was replaced.

**EDIT**

Wrote a JSBin with the problem here: http://jsbin.com/jijalugu/1/edit?html,js,output

Looks like it's a filter that's causing the problem. I'm using the filter to split the objects into partitions (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap)). Not sure why, it works correctly without the filter.

Comment: Is it unacceptable for you to redraw the chart when the scope data changes?

Comment: Yes, the scope changes frequently and the chart takes too long to render.

Comment: You have A chart or a chart for every object?

Comment: A chart for every object

Comment: Hmm... Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RUfPX/ Doesn't look like it's clearing the div when the model is changed. What is different in your situation?

Comment: Thanks @Lukas. Here's the a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/vufatapo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Actually, here's an even simpler example without charts: http://jsbin.com/jijalugu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [tracking expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

```
<div ng-repeat="rows in items | partition:2  track by $index" class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="item in rows">
    <b>{{ item.title }}</b>
    <div id="chart-{{item.title}}" class="chart"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ben Nadel has an excellent blog post [explaining tracking expressions](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-Using-Track-By-With-ngRepeat-In-AngularJS-1-2.htm) and their benefits:

> This feature allows you to associate a JavaScript object with an ngRepeat DOM (Document Object Model) node using a unique identifier. With this association in place, AngularJS will not $destroy and re-create DOM nodes unnecessarily. This can have a huge performance and user experience benefit.

Comment: I've never been this impressed with a SO answer. Thank you! That worked perfectly. I'm going to wait 2 days to accept your answer to give you a bounty.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.  That was a great JSBin demo, by the way.