# How to wrap parts of an ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can one, if at all possible, do the following:

```
<ul>
<li ng-reapeat="a in c"></li>
</ul>
```

with an output like this:

```
<ul>    
    <div>        
        <li></li> <--- from a to b (say first till 3rd element)        
        <li></li>
        ...
    </div>    
    <div>
        <li></li> <--- from b to c (4th element till end)
        <li></li>
        ...
    </div>
</ul>
```

Or even multiple `<ul></ul>` blocks. First one closing at a designated index, second one opening and continuing until the end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to split the ng-repeat data with three columns using bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array (probably not an "angular way"), for example

```
<ul>
  <div> 
    <li ng-repeat="a in c.slice(0, 3)"></li>
  </div>

  <div> 
    <li ng-repeat="a in c.slice(3)"></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Most efficient answer. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

General idea, you should be able to get what you want using this pattern

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat-start="a in c" ng-show="$index<3"></li>
  <li ng-repeat-end ng-show="$index>=3"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

I think you need multiple ul blocks.

```
<ul>    
  <div ng-reapeat="a in c">        
    <li ng-if="$index<3"></li> 
  </div>    
</ul>


 <ul>    
  <div ng-reapeat="a in c">        
    <li ng-if="$index>2"></li> 
  </div>    
 </ul>
```

Hope it helps...!

Comment: Most likely a valid answer. Will try it out comparing the other answers as well.