# Show multiple trs with multiple tds using custom partition

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am loading my items into table with multiple rows and multiple td. I have used partition custom filter from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap) link

This is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JKBbV/506/)

```
myApp.filter('partition', function() {
  var cache = {};
  var filter = function(arr, size) {
    if (!arr) { return; }
    var newArr = [];

      if(size>arr.length)
          size=arr.length;

    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) {
      newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
    }

    var arrString = JSON.stringify(arr);
    var fromCache = cache[arrString+size];
    if (JSON.stringify(fromCache) === JSON.stringify(newArr)) {
      return fromCache;
    }
    cache[arrString+size] = newArr;
    return newArr;
  };
  return filter;
});
```

When I give more that 4 elements its working properly. But when I provide only single product that td is occupying whole tr. I just want to have that td occupying its allocated space so that border looks good. If anybody can find workaround, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not occupying the whole `tr`, it is because the width property of the CSS style. So, change

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 50px">
```

to

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
```

And it will show correctly.