# Push down a series of divs when another div is shown

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do this when someone clicks a box:

[image]

It's seems simple, if I put the gray div inside the `ng-repeat`, when a user clicks a box, the new div would be shown.

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-click...>
 <div>
   {{friend}}
 </div>
 <div collapse="expand">
  some content
 </div>
</div>
```

But, what if I don't want to repeat the gray div? (Let's say it's a bunch of `html` that is not necessary to be repeat by each element).

So, I have **[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xt8a4SKrXYtnHswlHdzM?p=preview)**, where the gray div is outside the ng-repeat.

Is it any possibility to do what you see in the image with **pure CSS** or some trick in angular or javascript?

I heard that I could use jQuery to inject the html, but maybe could exist a cleaner way.

Considerations:

- A row could have one to `n` items.

What I have tried

- Put the gray div with `position relative`, but this would not push down the other divs.

Comment: Maybe make this bunch of code a directive is the correct way?

Comment: That's right, but putting it in a directive would not get the main problem, this is, avoiding the repetition of that directive by each item.

Comment: You need to wrap your collapse into a directive. The directive can take out the entire part out of the DOM and store it inside itself. You can then trigger it with a click, and let it be inserted on the right spot. You need to read out the DOM and do some calculation to get it inserted at the right spot, but it is well possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your task is unachievable unless you change markup. The result should be like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Age
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Age
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Age
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Age
  </div>
</div>
```

For that you need to use custom filter. I took it from here
[how to split the ng-repeat data with three columns using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap)

Since you use jQuery you can easily manipulate elements now. You can get you collapse div and append it to every row.

You modified working planker is here
http://plnkr.co/edit/WUGDcUsxqRqrrmK4I9Lh?p=preview

Comment: Hmmm, it seems to be a good solution, now I only have to calculate which the last item of each row is.

Comment: I edited plunker and added that too. Now you can see triangle different position depending on div you click.