# How can I start a new row on some specific index in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**what i am trying to achieve:** what i want to achieve is that to add an new row of ul after every 2 elements in my ng-repeat loop

for example

```
                 <ul class="col-sm-2">
                            <li><p>Automobile & Motorcycle</p></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Diagnostic Tools</a></li>


                  </ul>  
                   <ul class="col-sm-2">
                            <li><p>Automobile & Motorcycle</p></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Diagnostic Tools</a></li>


                   </ul>
```

no how can i do this in `ng-repea`t?

is there any possiblity using `ng-repeat-start/end`

i havent been able to try any thing in angular view as i am not able to make any logic sorry for that, but i can get this done with java script by

```
for (index=0,i=0,j=$scope.items.length; i<j; i+=chunk,index++) {
    temparray [index]= $scope.items.slice(i,i+chunk);
   }
   $scope.items =temparray;
```

or

```
$scope.groupByTwo = function (array)
    {
    var newarray =[];
    index=0;
    for(a=0;a<array.length;a++){
       if(a==0 || a%2==0){
          newarray[index]=[];
          newarray[index].push(array[a]);
      }else{
         newarray[index].push(array[a]);
      }
    if(a!=0)
    index++;

    }
  return newarray;
}
  $scope.items=$scope.groupByTwo($scope.items);
```

**Question** is their any angular way of doing this cleanly?

Comment: try using something like `ng-if="$index%3!==0"`

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="one">
     <div ng-repeat="b in getLength()  track by $index">
        <ul ng-repeat="a in getArray($index)">
            <li><p>{{a}}</p></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <script>
       var app=angular.module("app",[]);
       app.controller("one",function($scope){
        $scope.data=['one','two','three','four'];
         $scope.getLength=function(){
           console.log($scope.data.length/2);
           return new Array($scope.data.length/2);
         };
         $scope.getArray=function(index){
           var temparray;
           console.log(index);
              temparray= $scope.data.slice(index*2,index*2+2);
              console.log(temparray)
          return temparray;
         }
       })
     </script>
  </body>
```

Plunker link :- "http://plnkr.co/edit/s3ZMCnWdjG2VI6HNdlVp?p=preview"

Comment: thanks for answer @squirod but is it possible with views only i have written js also i want to do it in views

Comment: You need two values at a time to display in <ul></ul> but it is not possible with the ng-repeat as far as i know sorry...

Comment: "http://plnkr.co/edit/joOHkFLLiYQhfIhzuVJM?p=preview" Almost in view except convert the number into array.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments yet, so I'm making a suggestion based on @squiroid answer. His suggestion is *pretty* close, but not quite complete. In his example, the `<div/>` is behaving the way you want the `<ul/>` to behave, but the `<ul/>` is still repeating for each item. I also included the distinction between the even and odd `<li/>`s by making the odds a link.

Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/s72vWHPJ1CIOzrmlPfHg?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
  <ul ng-repeat="group in getGroups() track by $index">
    <li ng-repeat="data in getDataByGroup($index)">
        <p ng-if='$even'>{{data}}</p>
        <p><a href='#' ng-if='$odd'>{{data}}</a></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
      $scope.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

      $scope.getGroups = function() {
        return new Array($scope.data.length / 2);
      };

      $scope.getDataByGroup = function(index) {
        return $scope.data.slice(index * 2, index * 2 + 2);
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for answer @bbennett but is it possible with views only i have written js also i want to do it in views

Comment: I don't believe there is. 1. `ng-repeat` must be placed on an element causing that element to be rendered n times unless you use `ng-show` or `ng-if`. 2. using `ng-show` or `ng-if` will prevent child elements from rendering also. Both put you in a bind for what you want. Also, since your data is a flat array with no other properties to group on, you need to make the pseudo group like above to generate your `<ul/>`s properly. A cleaner solution would be to wrap the js into a filter like so: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21653981/3413194](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21653981/3413194)

Comment: plus one for your answer, but i hope i can make it work someway, yeah i think this isnt possible with view

Comment: Thanks and good luck. I think creating a chunk filter (like the link illustrates) with whatever JavaScript logic you want to use is the best approach I've seen. Plus its a handy piece of code to prevent other developers from having to duplicate the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-show and the $index of your repeated elements. Check if the index is even by using the condition ($index % 2 == 0):

```
<ul class="col-sm-2" ng-show="$index%2==0"></ul>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: but this will hide the inner elements  aslo, can you eloborate more?