# display 5 column every row in ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

please help me..

i'm create project with ionic.
i want to display 5 column every row.

this is my code

```
<div class="row responsive-sm" ng-repeat="item in products">
    <div class="col"  >
        <div class="list card" >

            <div class="item">
                <h2>{{item.merk}}</h2>
                <p>Nine Inch Nails</p>
            </div>

            <div class="item item-image">
                <img ng-src="http://kaerusshop.com/users/rahadian/merk/{{item.pict}}">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

code above display one row to view all data

how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chunk it.

Since Ionic is Angular under the hood, take a look at this post, it should solve it for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653981/5210

Comment: You might also check this.  It uses just AngularJS and CSS, but in this example I did four images per row.  https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/03/make-a-gallery-like-image-grid-using-ionic-framework/

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
</div>
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-even