# How do I split Angular UI Bootstrap accordions into multiple columns?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to split accordion directives into multiple columns.  This is what I have so far:

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="d in dimensions" heading="{{d.name}}">
        {{d.description}}
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Right now, it displays the accordions in a line straight down the page, like so:

```
Acc1
Acc2
Acc3
Acc4
Acc5
Acc6
```

I would like it to be split up like so into N columns (3 in this case):

```
Acc1    Acc2    Acc3
Acc4    Acc5    Acc6
```

Right now I am looking at a filter approach, but I am curious if there is a better way.

The controller logic right now is essentially limited to populating `$scope.dimensions`.

[Here is a plunker showing the basics](http://plnkr.co/edit/gbPVD9HX5KfK24T90iFF?p=preview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to split the ng-repeat data with three columns using bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one "cheap" (implementation-wise) way to achieve is by filtering the index with `mod 3`, and using `class="col-*-4"`:

```
<div class="row">
  <accordion>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <accordion-group heading="{{d.name}}" ng-repeat="d in dimensions" 
                       ng-if="$index % 3 === 0">
        {{d.description}}
      </accordion-group>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <accordion-group heading="{{d.name}}" ng-repeat="d in dimensions" 
                       ng-if="$index % 3 === 1">
        {{d.description}}
      </accordion-group>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <accordion-group heading="{{d.name}}" ng-repeat="d in dimensions" 
                       ng-if="$index % 3 === 2">
        {{d.description}}
      </accordion-group>
    </div>
  </accordion>
</div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tuK0wZY0i1gI03XqLlux?p=preview)

The better approach would be to pre-prepare the `dimensions` array into the proper form first.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I ended up doing :)