# Data Normalization using lodash, javascript

Tags: angularjs, lodash, normalization, jquery-ui-sortable

Data normalization from two dimensional to 1 dimension using lodash

```
rel      href

link1    url1

link2    url2

link3    url3  url4

link4    url4  url5
```

**Expected after Normalization**

```
rel      href

link1    url1

link2    url2

link3    url3 

link3    url4

link4    url4 

link4    url5
```

I create a file here but it didn't give me expected result using lodash methods

http://plnkr.co/edit/jijIkVwOLDSoA8IhiNc6?p=preview

```
function update(data) {
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].href.length > 1) {
                    var a = data[i].href.length;
                    for (var j = 0; j < a; j++) {
                        updatedata.push(data[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
    return updatedata;
}

var updatedata=[{ rel: '', href: []}];

var data = [
    { rel: 'link1', href: ['url1']},
    { rel: 'link2', href: ['url2']},
    { rel: 'link3', href: ['url3' , 'url6']},
    { rel: 'link4', href: ['url4' , 'url5']}
];

console.log(update(data));
```

Comment: You changed the entire question...please marked it as answered and make a new question instead....our answers don't make any sense in this context now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a nested ng-repeat for the addresses per user and can conditionally show/hide it if you want on click.  If you share your code in a snippet here with the problem (or in plnkr.co) then I can show a fixed version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just update the question please take a look

Answer (score 0):

m59 does a much better job here of explaining

[how to split the ng-repeat data with three columns using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap)

you can filter the results via a controller and return an array containing objects(each address) and ng-repeats uses this to generate rows. two way binding the address input to will allow ng-repeat to dynamically create rows as the user types!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just update the question please take a look.

Comment: You added lodash....do you even need it? Your code is much more complicated than it needs to be. I'm on a phone so I can't code much but it seems unnecessarily complex

Comment: Can u give me a simple approach?

Comment: Follow the link I posted. BTW, you could try pushing all urls into one array. Then a function inserts them sequentially into the final data object.