# How to display the <i> icon next to the middle elements of a set of paragraphs attached within a label in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have the below structure in html:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary demo-review" ng-model="demo.ids" ng-click="selectMe($event,3)" btn-radio="'{{demo.demoinfo.ids}}'">
        <i class="check-circle btn-success selected" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p ng-repeat="race in demo.demoinfo.selectedRaces track by $index" class="text-center">
          {{race.racename}}<br />
        </p>
      </label>
```

As you can see here I am rendering  number of race elements using ng-repeat.
But the  icons is a bootstrap one, which is coming right side of the top race element.
What I want is to render that icon right next to the middle race element. So, if there are 5 elements, it should be next to the 3rd, if there are 4 elements it should be next to the 2nd.

Is it possible to do in AngularJS ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752526/how-to-use-ng-repeat-for-creating-the-list-of-m-items-in-thumbnail-format-having/33752849#33752849

Answer (score 0):

You could use the index and the length of the array in an expression.

```
<label class="btn btn-primary demo-review" ng-model="demo.ids" ng-click="selectMe($event,3)" btn-radio="'{{demo.demoinfo.ids}}'">
    <p ng-repeat="race in demo.demoinfo.selectedRaces track by $index" class="text-center">
        <i class="check-circle btn-success selected" aria-hidden="true" 
            ng-show="($index * 2 + 2) === demo.demoinfo.selectedRaces.length || ($index * 2 + 1) === demo.demoinfo.selectedRaces.length"></i>
            {{race.racename}}<br />
    </p>
</label>
```

It would be cleaner if you injected `Math` into the scope (you will be able to use `Math.floor`)

Comment: It is taking them as comment instead of generating <i> element.

Comment: Don't think it is taking as a comment (because with no CSS if I put something within the <i> tags you can see the tag). It's probably your CSS that's causing it to collapse - could you set up a fiddle? Cheers!