# How to calculate a transaction in ng-if and put a `<div>` only if the condition is true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i want to add a row only if the `x` in `$scope.grp` leaves no remainder when divided by 3. I was trying the following code.

```
 <div class="card">
  <div ng-repeat="x in grp">
     <div class="row">
        <div ng-if="x%3==0">
           <div class="row">
        </div>
    <div class="col col-33">
       /my rest of code here/
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
<div>
```

any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: can you show the contents of `grp`?

Comment: can you share your angularJs code

Comment: Is it working? Or you just need suggestions?

Comment: that should work if `grp` is just an array of numbers

Comment: @zan `app.controller("creatMessageController",function($scope,$http,$cookies) {
   var userId=$cookies.get('userId');
   var password=$cookies.get('password');
    $http.get("http://www.mysite.in/userGroups/1/100?userId="+userId+"&password="+password)
   .then(function(response){$scope.grp=response.data.msg;},function()
     {
      location.assign("error.html");
     })`

Comment: @jithin i need suggestion to make it work. i need to break the flow and add a `<div class="row">` so that i have a symmetric `<div class="col col-33">` .

Comment: Do you by any change actually want to wrap every three values/columns in a row div?

Comment: @IonutCostica Yes. i have a another card of 33(col) width. I want to wrap 3 such cols in one div row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to split the ng-repeat data with three columns using bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap)

Comment: In that case, the question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap . Take a look there, it has a great answer on how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether the following is correct or not. But a way to achieve it is as following.

```
<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="grp=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']" class="container">
  <div ng-repeat="x in grp" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-3">{{grp[$index]}}</div>
     <div class="col-xs-3" ng-if="$index + 1 < grp.length">{{grp[$index+1]}}</div>
     <div class="col-xs-3" ng-if="$index + 2 < grp.length">{{grp[$index+2]}}</div>
   </div>
<div>
```

I am assuming `grp` is a string array and used `$index` to group.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/26b40s5q/)

Comment: using $index has somehow solved my problem trying the later part of it now. Hope it works. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
if reminder is 0, row will be added

```
<div class="card">
<div ng-repeat="x in grp">
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-if="x%3==0">
      <div class="row">
        reminder 0
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-33">
      my rest of code here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for controller

```
function ctrl($scope){
   $scope.grp=[1,2,3];   
}
```

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJJKwr

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with angularjs - however your html struct is wrong in this case. Your struct will create an empty "row" column before every third div. I don't know if there is a way to just open a "div" tag in an ng-if and close it at a later point.

You should consider just creating array chunks for your cards. So each chunk will hold 3 cards and then you can loop over the first level of chunks, and then over the second level of your array. It will look something like that:

```
<div class="card">
    <div ng-repeat="grp in chunks">
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-repeat"x in grp"> // as mentioned, I got no clue about angularjs, so I don't know how to correctly address the values within the groups
                <div class="col col-33">
                    my rest of code here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As mentioned before I have no clue about angularjs itself, however you should be able to create chunks (split your array into smaller arrays) like:

```
var chunks=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
```