# show items in specific order angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i have a array of suppose 8 items

```
var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

now in my requirement the user can specify the number of columns in which the data can be displayed suppose the user selects 3 columns than the structure should be

```
1   4   7
2   5   8
3   6
```

how to achieve this using angularjs in table structure. So Result should be like this only....

```
<table>
   <tr><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>7</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>8</td></tr>
   <tr><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: without specifiying rows how can you display? Provide your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap