# Angular 2 ngFor row and columns created one big Col

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

Apparently ngfor generates divisions of the divs one by one, and when it finishes placing all the divs one down the other, presenting a bad design, I want to get something like this:

```
[1] [2] [3]
[4] [5] [6]
```

And only as a result I have:

```
[ 1 ]
[ 2 ]
[ 3 ]
  and continues..
```

**My JSON is something like this:**

```
[
  {
    "id_nivel": "1",
    "nombre": "A",
    "constelacion": "AA",
    "descripcion": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
  },
  {
    "id_nivel": "2",
    "nombre": "B",
    "constelacion": "BB",
    "descripcion": "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
  },
  {
    "id_nivel": "3",
    "nombre": "C",
    "constelacion": "CC",
    "descripcion": "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"
  },
  {
    "id_nivel": "4",
    "nombre": "D",
    "constelacion": "DD",
    "descripcion": "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"
  },
  {
    "id_nivel": "5",
    "nombre": "E",
    "constelacion": "EE",
    "descripcion": "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"
  },
  {
    "id_nivel": "6",
    "nombre": "F",
    "constelacion": "FF",
    "descripcion": "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"
  }
]
```

**The main problem:**

```
<div class="app flex-row align-items-center">   
<div class="container">
        <div *ngFor="let data of Const" class="row"> 
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card col-md-4">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Level {{data.id_nivel}} - {{data.nombre}} </h4>
                        <p class="card-text"> {{data.descripcion}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**More info in this Plunker:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/e5K5oiKL2n9IdHM5qk1v?p=preview

Comment: This could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace with the below HTML

```
<div class="app flex-row align-items-center">   
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="card-deck row">
            <div class="card col-md-6" *ngFor="let data of Const">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Level {{data.id_nivel}} - {{data.nombre}} </h4>
                    <p class="card-text"> {{data.descripcion}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screen shot
[image]
**[Updated Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/4c0WhLHCfPn2v7oCWF2E?p=preview)**

Comment: @NewKey was my answer helpful?

Comment: It help me, but occurs a little problem http://puu.sh/tOzbF.png and is exactly as you posted, I tried with css block it with column-count and others but nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

Change the html as below and it works now

```
<div class="app flex-row align-items-center">   
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="card-deck row">
            <div class="card col-md-4" *ngFor="let data of Const">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Level {{data.id_nivel}} - {{data.nombre}} </h4>
                    <p class="card-text"> {{data.descripcion}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```