# AngularJS - How to repeat row in ng-repeat at window resize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, media-queries, window-resize

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653981/65681) to repeat rows after col-* from ng repeat.

Now to take this one step further and handle an additional code I would like to handle the splitting with `$(window).width()` within the controller, but I couldn't achieve doing so...

Here is [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5gojtzqdJavkBEQLwSeA?p=preview) of what I've done. I've commented the `if` condition which is not working for now.

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Plunker not working. At least on my end on FF.

Comment: Works for me buddy, tried opening in incognito too. Just in case here is the link again https://plnkr.co/edit/5gojtzqdJavkBEQLwSeA Make sure you run it

Comment: try inject $window into your controller. it works!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Angular, jQuery and JavaScript as a whole for setting up the number of items which will be shown on a different resolutions. This is a CSS issue.
Besides that you can use jQuery in Angular in a `directive`, not in the `controller`. The controller is not used for DOM manipulations as in it, it has to be the business logic for a specific module. 
Angular has a build-in `angular.element` which (if jQuery is available), is an alias for jQuery function. It wraps a raw DOM element or HTML string as a jQuery element. If jQuery's not available, `angular.element` delegates to AngularJS's built-in subset of jQuery, called `jQuery lite` or `jqLite`. 
You can read more information about using jQuery in Angular [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

```
$window
```

is Angular service which reference to the browser's `window` object. You should inject it into the controller in order to use it in your controller's functions.

Answer (score 1):

you need to watch the window resize event with jquery, this is what you need

```
$(window).resize(function(){


    $scope.$apply(function(){
       if ($(window).width() >= 990){   
        $scope.teamMembers = $scope.chunk($scope.allMembers, 4);
     } else if ($(window).width() <= 991)  {
        $scope.teamMembers = $scope.chunk($scope.allMembers, 2);
         }
    });
  });
```

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ZVQg46noboME2TxuPM0?p=preview)