# Bootstrap dynamic divider for columns (angular solution preferable)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Let's say I have a typical bootstrap layout with `row`'s and `col-lg-x`'s

```
<div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7">

        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Are there any plugins (perferably angular but others too) to make a draggable divider between 2 columns to allows the user to adjust the width?

Like in [this example](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/layout_inside_tab.html) (Tab #2)  except it should "snap" to bootstrap's possible col-lg-xx combinations like col-6/col-6, col-5/col-7, col-4/col-8.

Comment: I made this slightly less than perfect one a while ago, but it does most of the work: http://codepen.io/pprice/pen/splkc, it wouldnt take much to turn this into a directive

Comment: thanks Phil but not quite what I'm looking for I need it to use standard bootstrap styles like row, col-x, and snap to specific col-x combinations.

Comment: [handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) support both bootstrap tables and column re sizing. I integrated it with angular very quickly - it's very well build and documented.

Comment: Thanks haki but Im not looking for a table plugin. I looked at the plugin but it's too overkill for what I'm trying to do, it'll end up like hack job for several reasons. I literally have a single divider on the page it would be crazy to make the entire site a table with 2 columns, plus it wont snap. Thanks though :)

Comment: Did you try making a directive for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this that worked for you? I am looking to do something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following does not address your question directly, in that it does not follow bootstrap's columns/rows. But it might give you a good starting point and others might find it useful:

`bg-splitter` https://github.com/blackgate/bg-splitter

`ui-layout` https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout

Answer (score 1):

There are good Angular solutions in this answer:
[Angular.js using bootstrap and dynamically creating rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748449/angular-js-using-bootstrap-and-dynamically-creating-rows)

As well as this answer:
[how to split the ng-repeat data with three columns using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap/21653981#21653981)