# Watch for filtering event in AngularJS - lazy loading images

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to watch for the filtering event from within my directive when filtering on ngRepeat occurs. Is there an event that gets emitted when filtering occurs?

What I am doing is implementing lazy loading of images for a list of thumbnails. It works but when I start filtering, the images that were out of viewport and come into view after filtering need to get their ng-src attribute replaced.

**Here is the directive:**

```
TemplateBrowser.directive('lazySrc', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        function replaceSrc() {
            if (element.is(":in-viewport")) {
                attrs.$set('ngSrc', attrs.lazySrc);
            }
        }

        $(window).scroll( function() {
            replaceSrc();
        });

        scope.$watch('filteredTemplates', function() {
            replaceSrc();
        });
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="template in filteredTemplates = ( templates | filterByCategory: selectedCategories | filter: searchFilter )">
  <img ng-src="" lazy-src="{{template.cover.thumb.url}}" alt="">
</li>
```

**Currently I get this error:**

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

**TLDR:**
Instead of watching a filtered collection for changes, is there a way to emit some kind of filtering event that the directive will listen to?
(filtering occurs through a search field and a categories selection menu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you don't have a stabilized model in your ng-repeat directive.

If you initialize filteredTemplates model beforehand you should see that it's working:

```
<ul ng-init="filteredTemplates=( templates | filterByCategory: selectedCategories | filter: searchFilter )">
    <li ng-repeat="template in filteredTemplates">
    ...
```

I've created a Fiddle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/f757U/

You can find detailed explanations regarding this behaviour in the following posts:

- [How to Loop through items returned by a function with ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat)
- [Infinite $digest() loop when using a function in ng:repeat](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/705)
- [Problem with nested ngRepeat - Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/Ib6YhFV3Xf4)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, that project was on hold for a while. This seems to work if you have the data right away. I am running into problems once the data is a promise. Thanks for the nudge forward though!

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, but I need it work like this. http://jsfiddle.net/f757U/

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://github.com/revolunet/rn-lazy

There is also [carousel](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel) solution from same brilliant guys

Comment: It doesn't seem like rn-lazy is actually a lazy loading implementation. All it does is showing a spinner while image is loading. What I was trying to achieve is preventing the client from requesting the images unless they are actually in viewport since it would save a lot of data / requests on a page filled with images.