# what are $$hashkey objects in Angularjs? How can I read multiple file inputs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to get multiple file attachments from file inputs using the following directive:

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap']).config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{|');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('|}');
    }
).directive('ngFile',function(){
            return {
            scope: {
                ngFile: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, el, attrs){
                el.bind('change', function(event){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.ngFile = event.target.files[0];
                    });

                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Now I have the following bit of angular/template code bellow

```
<div ng-repeat="attachment in messages.attachments">
    ... some html code
    <input type="file" ng-file="attachment">
    ... some more html
</div>
```

I'm trying to access my files via:

```
$scope.messages.attachments[ someIndex ] // Returns $$hashkey
```

But all this is doing is return some hash key $$hashkey.

Question 1) What exactly is this $$hashkey object and what is it used for?

Question 2) How can I access my files use $scope.messages.attachments?

Comment: `$$hashkey` is a property that angular adds to every object utilized within any scope. It is for internal angular use. Probably need to use the browser formData API to get more on files

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23656919/1444541

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the $$hashKey added to my JSON.stringify result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826320/what-is-the-hashkey-added-to-my-json-stringify-result)