# How to get plain object from $scope in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am putting the downloaded json object into an angular $scope, but I found that angular adds some framework dependent properties inside it.

I want to send the modified object back to server, is there a convenient way I can remove angular properties and get the plain object without angular scope properties like `$$hashkey`?

**EDIT:**

The possible duplicate question does not provide the answer I needed.

Calling `angular.toJson` gives me a plain string `"$SCOPE"`, while calling `angular.copy` throws an error. I guess they are not designed to work with the $scope object itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the $$hashKey added to my JSON.stringify result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826320/what-is-the-hashkey-added-to-my-json-stringify-result)

Comment: I've heard that Angular strips properties prefixed with $$ before sending them to the server. The [toJson() function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) does this, and [$http seems to use it](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L129). Though I'm a bit too lazy to verify it in a browser :)

Comment: Sunil is correct, `angular.toJson(obj)` will do the trick.

Comment: `angular.copy()` will also strip $$hashkey's

Comment: calling `angular.toJson` with $scope gives me the string `"$SCOPE"`, while `angular.copy` throws a an error `Error: [ng:cpws] Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/ng/cpws`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the `angular.toJson` doesn't support the `$scope` object as you can see in the source code: [Angular.js#L979](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.18/src/Angular.js#L979)

You could use the `JSON.stringify()` with a custom replacer function and copy a part of the logic in `angular.toJson()` like this;

```
JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
  if (typeof key === 'string' && (key.charAt(0) === '$' || key === 'this')) {
    // ignore any key start with '$',
    // and also ignore 'this' key to avoid a circular reference issue.
    return undefined;
  }

  return value;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This kind of helps, I think they designed scopes in a way that this kind of usage is not recommended. I ended up wrapping the object into a scope property instead.