# Assign unique id to js array without changing structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have lots of JS arrays like the following:

```
 q = [{
      "v": "blah",
          "t": "asdfsdf",
 }, {
      "v": "basldfasdfd",
          "t": "blah",
 }...]
```

I'd like to assign unique id's to them, and then attach those id's to buttons, essentially. However, I'm not sure where I should put the id's without changing the structure of the JS array. I'm building an angular JS app and in the chrome dev tools, I've noticed a `$$hashkey` for each element. Does the entire array have a property like that? If so, how can I use it, and will it change if the array changes (which it will)?

I'd like to avoid further nesting, ie, I'd prefer to avoid having to do something like

```
q = {
  data: [whatever was above],
  meta: { id: 234234324, ... }
};
```

Is that the only way? If so, then in AngularJS, instead of doing `ng-repeat="item in q"`, I would just do `ng-repeat="item in q.data"`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Angular adds $$hashKey to keep track of your changes, so it knows when it needs to update the DOM. ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23656919/2988788))

> ```
> q = {
>   data: [whatever was above],
>   meta: { id: 234234324, ... }
> };
> ```
>
> Is that the only way?

I don't see why i would use another structure, this one is good.

> If so, then in angularJS, instead of doing `ng-repeat="item in q"`, I
>   would just do `ng-repeat="item in q.data"`, right?

Yes

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use lodash's [`_.indexBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy)

It will convert your array to an object that you can call by keys

```
var q = [{
    "v": "blah",
    "t": "asdfsdf",
}, {
    "v": "basldfasdfd",
    "t": "blah",
}];

// returns an object that has the value of v as the key
console.log(_.indexBy(q, 'v'));

// returns an object that has the value of t as the key
console.log(_.indexBy(q, 't'));
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wnnr0hza/

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `lodash_.indexBy()`. Can you explain it a little or provide an example? Thanks!

Comment: @thatandrey added the lodash indexBy example

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. Actually, what I wanted to do was index q as an object, not it's individual members, since I'll be having lots of q's. I guess there's really no better way than what I suggested as an option?