# ng-repeat on array of objects produces $$hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-ng-repeat

An example of the data that I am using:

```
[
  {  
   objectId: "lBrweaVVKd"
   url: "http://files.parsetfss.com/5f0d29c3-6b71-4029-8bd8-c2db01a82bbc/tfss-cf720b16-08f9-46ed-b23e-1e626aImage"
  },
  {
   objectId: "lBrweaVVKd"
   url: "http://files.parsetfss.com/5f0d29c3-6b71-4029-8bd8-c2db01a82bbc/tfss-cf720b16-08f9-46ed-b23e-1e626aImage"
  }
]
```

and using an `ng-repeat` in my template like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="image in activeExercise.images track by $index" ng-model="activeExercise.images">
    <img ng-if="isNumber(image)" src="http://file.s3.amazonaws.com/medium/{{image}}.jpg" />
    <img ng-if="!isNumber(image)" src="{{image.url}}"></div>
</div>
```

(I return my images from two locations, one is local and is just an image, and the other in parse.com which is a URL hence my `ng-if` unsure if this is causing my problems?)

When I push this into an array the `ng-repeat` is producing `$$hash`.

**The problem with this is Parse.com rejects anything with a `$` in it**

== EDIT ==
This is a sample of code where `track by $index` does not produce `$$hash`

```
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="sliderimage in activeExercise.images track by $index">
        <div ng-if="isNumber(sliderimage)" image-lazy-src="http://rehabgurufiles.s3.amazonaws.com/medium/{{sliderimage}}.jpg"></div>
        <div ng-if="!isNumber(sliderimage)" class="modalSliderThumbnail" image-lazy-src="{{sliderimage.url}}"></div>
    </ion-slide>
```

== EDIT 2 ==
The help a little more:

This receives a number :

```
<div ng-if="isNumber(sliderimage)" image-lazy-src="http://urufiles.s3.amazonaws.com/medium/{{sliderimage}}.jpg">
```

This receives an object as described above:

```
<img ng-if="!isNumber(image)" src="{{image.url}}"></div>
```

Comment: is the div also in your ionic project? or are there 2 different versions of angular being used?

Comment: Yes - this is all the same app. The slide `<ion-slide>` version is just a different way of displaying the same thing as the `<div>` version.

Comment: it seems like it's using the same array to populate the images. I created a plnkr to see if having multiple ng-repeats over the same array causes the $hash but wasn't able to duplicate. Are images being added to the `activeExercise.images` the same way? i.e. using the same method?

Answer (score 0):

Angular adds the $$hashKey [See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826320/what-is-the-hashkey-added-to-my-json-stringify-result)

You need to remove this before you send the data to parse. `delete itm.$$hashKey` would work in your function before sending the data

Comment: Ideally I would like it not to every be in my object - I understood that `track by $index` would stop it being added?

Comment: I have read that as well, that track by will make it so $$hashKey is not added. I have not personally tested this.

Comment: I use `track by $index` elsewhere in my app and it has worked to correct this problem elsewhere in my app however it is not working in this case.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your code where track by $index is being used and the $$hashKey isn't being added?