# remove $$hashKey from array

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.appdata = [{name: '', position: '', email: ''}];
```

This is the array which I created in angular controller.

Then I inserted some values in to array by using push method:

```
$scope.appdata.push({name: 'jenson raby', position: '2', email: 'jensonraby@gmail.com'});
```

This is the array values after insertion:

```
$$hashKey:"00F",name:"jenson raby",position:"2",email:"jensonraby@gmail.com",
```

Here an extra `$$hashKey` has been added to the array after insertion, but I need to remove this from array.

Comment: Are you using any AngularJS service to handle Rest API ike Restangular?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to remove the `$$hashKey`, but if your question really is "What is the `$$hashKey`?", [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826320/what-is-the-hashkey-added-to-my-json-stringify-result).

Comment: i need to insert the above array to database, that's why i need to remove

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Based on your comment that you need to insert the array into the database, I'm going to assume that you are converting it a JSON string and then saving it to the DB. If that's incorrect, let me know and I'll see if I can revise this answer.

You have two options for modifying your array when converting it to JSON. The first is [`angular.toJson`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson), which is a convenience method that automatically strips out any property names with a leading `$$` prior to serializing the array (or object). You would use it like this:

```
var json = angular.toJson( $scope.appdata );
```

The other option, which you should use if you need more fine grained control, is the `replacer` argument to the built-in [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function. The replacer function allows you to filter or alter properties before they get serialized to JSON. You'd use it like this to strip `$$hashKey`:

```
var json = JSON.stringify( $scope.appdata, function( key, value ) {
    if( key === "$$hashKey" ) {
        return undefined;
    }

    return value;
});
```

Comment: @Sean, Hi Sean, I have one clarification that Is there any possibility to $$hashkey goes duplication? I have used JSOn.stringify(Obj) and I am able to see duplicate hashkey in DB.

Comment: @MdAslam I don't believe there's any guarantee of uniqueness with `$$hashKey` - it's just an ID Angular uses to keep track of changes. You should not use it as a unique identifier.

Comment: Great solution, it's perfect for my use case. Do you know if the replacer function mutates the original object ($scope.appdata in your example)?

Comment: @AdamSpecker It does not mutate the original object, just changes the way in which it gets stringified.

Answer (score 30):

Fast solution for lazy people :

```
JSON.parse(angular.toJson($scope.appdata))
```

Comment: I am puzzled, I am doing exactly this in google chrome and angularjs, tried also all other suggestions and $$hashKey still appears. When is it inserted there? Any hints?

Comment: I still haven't understood why it is happening but when I did this: `$scope.steps = JSON.parse(angular.toJson($scope.steps)); console.log($scope.steps);` the `$$hashKey` was there, if I saved it in a different variable which was not in an ng-repeat it worked.

Comment: I think Angular add $$hashkey to keep track of scope objects as an ID. This is called Mutability in Javascript.

Comment: VinGarcia, thank you!  Thanks to your lead I discovered that my ng-change was set to the same thing as my scope.  Namely ng-change="categories" and then $scope.categories = ... As soon as I changed ng-change to ng-change="category" the problem dissappeared!

Answer (score 0):

The code behind the angular.toJson method is as follows:

```
function toJson(obj, pretty) {
  if (isUndefined(obj)) return undefined;
  if (!isNumber(pretty)) {
    pretty = pretty ? 2 : null;
  }
  return JSON.stringify(obj, toJsonReplacer, pretty);
}
```

When the JSON.stringify method is called it will strip out anything that starts with $

```
function toJsonReplacer(key, value) {
  var val = value;

  if (typeof key === 'string' && key.charAt(0) === '$' && key.charAt(1) === '$') {
    val = undefined;
  } else if (isWindow(value)) {
    val = '$WINDOW';
  } else if (value &&  window.document === value) {
    val = '$DOCUMENT';
  } else if (isScope(value)) {
    val = '$SCOPE';
  }

  return val;
}
```

So to build on Sean's asnwer, you could override the JSON.stringify method to do exactly what you need it to do.
To see more from the documentation of angular visit: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/14221