# What is safe method to perform `Object.assign` when using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Basically I would like to perform `Object.assign` to get copy of my data, without anything that AngularJS attached in the past, it attaches now, or may attach in future versions.

Sure I can delete such property as `$$hashKey` after assignment but this approach is totally fragile, on the other hand I could manually construct the object with fields I want but this on the other hand is tiresome (and also fragile if I change definition of my source object).

Is there something solid in between?

Comment: You don't explain what is this 'data' and how comes that AngularJS attaches 'something' to it. Should it be mentioned that this is the most important part in the question?

Comment: @estus, data is any object for example you might have, but once you use it in context of Angular, say you use it as model, you may end with your data + Angular data attached to it. So later when you copy it, you copy Angular attached fields as well -- like `$$hashKey`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344495/remove-hashkey-from-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no other properties as `$$hashKey`, it is one of a kind.

All of Angular object helpers [are aware of this property and remove it at the end of the operation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.7/src/Angular.js#L358). `angular.extend` is a direct Angular counterpart of `Object.assign` and should be used instead.

Comment: Thank you! As for "there are no other properties" you are describing current state, there is no guarantee in future there would be no other property or more of them.

Comment: @greenoldman $$hashKey is there from the framework's childhood, I guess it is still there and is enumerable for compatibility reasons, the team may be qualified enough to not do this again. Any way, stick to `angular.extend({}, ...)` to take internals into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

`angular.copy` seems to be helpful in this case

Comment: Thank you, there is a difference though, `angular.copy` is deep copy, while `Object.assign` is a shallow copy.