# Create unique array based on property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I want to create an array that does not have repeated object(all objects are unique) based on object property and if it is unique I want to push it to this array.
Before sending it to my function I use:

```
vm.initResponse = angular.fromJson(response);
```

That push `$$hashKey` to each object.

```
    function initDropDown(list){
        console.log('initDropDown', list);
        for (var key in list) {
            //remove angularjs $$hashKey
            var obj = JSON.parse(angular.toJson(list[key]));
            //the object I want to push into new array
            var filter = {};
            filter.prop = obj.SUGNIA;
            //if indexOf returns -1 the array does not have this object
            if(vm.stockOptionsSelect.indexOf(filter) < 0){
                vm.stockOptionsSelect.push(filter);
            }

        }
    }
```

the list array has many objects with different `SUGNIA` and I want to create an array with all unique ones.

I have removed `$$hashKey` has explained [remove-hashKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344495/remove-hashkey-from-array) and using `indexOf` - [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp).

List data -

```
[
  {
    "uid": "23",
    "time": "2017-10-01 16:00:35.515",
    "SUGNIA": "stock",
    "SECURITYNAME": "IBM",
    "INDEX_IN_UI": 5
  },
  {
    "uid": "29",
    "SECURITYNUM": 629014,
    "time": "2017-09-28 16:32:26.432",
    "SUGNIA": "holdings",
    "SECURITYNAME": "FaceBook",

    "INDEX_IN_UI": 10
  },
  {
    "uid": "id",
    "time": "2017-09-28 16:33:20.25",
    "SUGNIA": "stock",
    "SECURITYNAME": "google",
    "INDEX_IN_UI": 0
  }
]
```

And my result should be :

```
[{"prop":"stock"}, {"prop":"holding"}]
```

But I get duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description) function does the comparison using strict equality `===` and since the object you're passing to this function is an object that was just created, it will always return `-1`.

To fix that, you can use the [...some(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function instead.

Here is an example:

```
if(!vm.stockOptionsSelect.some(e => e.prop == obj.SUGNIA)){
    vm.stockOptionsSelect.push({prop:obj.SUGNIA});
}
```

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use indexof object as that isn't looking at object properties but it's looking for reference to that filter object. Use some instead and look for identical object properties.

```
var hasItem = vm.stockOptionsSelect.some(item) {
    return item.prop === filter.prop
}
if(!hasItem) {
    vm.stockOptionsSelect.push(filter);
}
```

If you cant use some

```
var results = vm.stockOptionsSelect.filter(item) {
    return item.prop === filter.prop;
}
if(results.length === 0) {
    vm.stockOptionsSelect.push(filter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set` and `array#map` to get the unique `SUGNIA` value from your array `list`.

```js
var list = [{"uid": "23","time": "2017-10-01 16:00:35.515","SUGNIA": "stock","SECURITYNAME": "IBM","INDEX_IN_UI": 5},{"uid": "29","SECURITYNUM": 629014,"time": "2017-09-28 16:32:26.432","SUGNIA": "holdings","SECURITYNAME": "FaceBook","INDEX_IN_UI": 10},{"uid": "id","time": "2017-09-28 16:33:20.25","SUGNIA": "stock","SECURITYNAME": "google","INDEX_IN_UI": 0}];

var result = [...new Set(list.map(x => x.SUGNIA))]
             .map(x => ({prop: x}));
             
console.log(result);
```