# Delete all keys from Object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have an array which looks like:

```
var standardsList = [
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality", "$$hashKey": "08932"},
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality", "$$hashKey": "07932"},
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality", "$$hashKey": "08332"},
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality", "$$hashKey": "08132"},
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry", "$$hashKey": "08902"} ];
```

This `$$hashKey` attribute is added by angularJS by default

I want to remove this `$$hashkey` attribute with value from all objects of above array.

Any pointers anyone ??

Comment: maybe you could refer to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826320/what-is-the-hashkey-added-to-my-json-stringify-result

Comment: @Nirvana did my answer solve this issue for you? Please mark it correct or place your own answer. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeat question / answer: [What is the $$hashKey added to my JSON.stringify result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826320/what-is-the-hashkey-added-to-my-json-stringify-result)

Angular adds this to keep track of your changes, so it knows when it needs to update the DOM.

If you use angular.toJson(obj) instead of JSON.stringify(obj) then Angular will strip out these internal-use values for you.

Also, if you change your repeat expression to use the track by {uniqueProperty} suffix, Angular won't have to add $$hashKey at all.

Otherwise this code will work to delete it:

```js
var standardsList = [
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality", "$$hashKey": "08932"},
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality", "$$hashKey": "07932"},
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality", "$$hashKey": "08332"},
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality", "$$hashKey": "08132"},
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry", "$$hashKey": "08902"} ];

for (var i=0; i<standardsList.length; i++){
  delete standardsList[i].$$hashKey;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(standardsList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map function to do this:

```
var newList = standardsList.map(function(obj){
   delete obj['$$hashKey'];

   return obj;
});
```

Comment: There's no need for `map` here, and in fact it's misleading.

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to use a `for each` loop:

```
for each (element in standardsList)
{
    delete element.$$hashKey;
}
```