# What is Resource type in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I debug my Angular application in Chrome I can see that some values are represented as "Resource". Each "Resource" has following values:

- `$$hashKey`
- `Disabled`
- `Group`
- `Selected`
- `Text`
- `Value`
- `__proto__`

`__proto__` is a "Resource" too and contains some functions, like `$delete`, `$get`, `$query`, `$remove` and `$save`. This gives me a cue it is somehow connected with Angular's `$resource` service.

Is this just a result of querying a web service using `$resource` service? If yes - can we create these objects (if "Resource" is an object) without querying service? On the other hand - can we retrieve data from services without this "Resource" overhead, just as plain data, without special processing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826320/what-is-the-hashkey-added-to-my-json-stringify-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indicates that the object was instantiated by [Resource](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0/src/ngResource/resource.js#L565) constructor. It is used internally by `$resource` service and isn't intended to be used outside of it, but it can - e.g. for testing purposes,

```
var Resource = $resource().prototype.constructor;
expect(someObj instanceof Resource).toBe(true);
```

> On the other hand - can we retrieve data from services without this
>   "Resource" overhead, just as plain data, without special processing?

`$resource` is a conventional solution for RESTful interactions in Angular. If the one considers it an 'overhead' and feels like its job can be done better than that, this wheel can be re-invented with `$http` (which `$resource` essentially uses to do what it does).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's good explanation. I just wanted to add I didn't mean $resource is overhead, but this additional fields returned by its get method. I thought maybe I use $resource wrong if mentioned fields exist in a result. As long as it is expected behavior and proper usage of $resource service I'm okay with it.