# How to skip $$hashKey in ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make some tables dynamically from an object. This is my Object

```
{
  categories: ["kids", "home"],
  home: [{
    name: "home 1.1",
    title: " home1.2"
  }, {
    name: "home 2.1",
    title: "home 2.2"
  }, {
    name: "home 3.1",
    title: "home 3.2"
  }, {
    name: "home 4.1",
    title: "home 4.2"
  }, {
    name: "home 5.1",
    title: "home 5.2"
  }],
  kids: [{
    name: "kids 1.1",
    title: "kids 1.2"
  }]
}
```

My running code is

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    categories: ["kids", "home"],
    home: [{
      name: "home 1.1",
      title: " home1.2"
    }, {
      name: "home 2.1",
      title: "home 2.2"
    }, {
      name: "home 3.1",
      title: "home 3.2"
    }, {
      name: "home 4.1",
      title: "home 4.2"
    }, {
      name: "home 5.1",
      title: "home 5.2"
    }],
    kids: [{
      name: "kids 1.1",
      title: "kids 1.2"
    }]
  };


  $scope.getKeys = function(obj) {
    if (!$scope.data.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {
      return [];
    }

    return Object.keys($scope.data[obj][0]);
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table ng-repeat="d in data.categories">
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="l in getKeys(d)" ng-if="$index != getKeys(d).length - 1">
        {{$index != getKeys(d).length - 1}} {{l}}
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="k in data[d]">
      <td>{{k.name}}</td>
      <td>{{k.title}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in the example, The condition `ng-if="$index != getKeys(d).length - 1"` is false, but it shows the **$$hashKey** column. How can I skip this??

I tried some of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826320/what-is-the-hashkey-added-to-my-json-stringify-result) answer's solutions :

- angular.copy()
- angular.toJson()
- `l != '$$hashKey'`

Now:

1. Why this condition is false, But it shows the column?
2. What is the correct way to get column names for each table?

Comment: Ok, please clear non-related comments under this post, as I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using very old version of AngularJS. This issue solved long ago from version `1.2.0` Check in below example I've created, it's working for all the versions of library from `1.2.0` to most recent 1.6.x

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DxkNZ02WnFun6rBQcgwl?p=preview)