# Nested list in angular.js filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple pagination filter for angular, to be used like so:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="page in items | paginate: 10">
        <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="item in page">{{ item }}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've written simple function:

```
angular.module('app.filters', [])
    .filter('paginate', function() {
        return function(input, perPage) {
            var pages = [],
                perPage = perPage || 10;

            for (i=0; i < input.length; i += perPage)
                pages.push(input.slice(i, i + perPage));

            return pages;
        };
    });
```

And it caused angular to crash with quite cryptic (for me at least) error messages. I figured out that the problem is in nested lists in filter results. To reproduce the problem, it's enough to do like this:

```
angular.module('app.filters', [])
    .filter('paginate', function() {
        return function(input, perPage) {
            return [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
        };
    });
```

Can you please tell me:

- why nested lists are a problem to angular filters?
- where can i read about it in documentation?
- how can i eventually write a filter in correct way?

You can see all code in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gUIJcJg0p5LqKGH10B8t?p=preview
After running the code, open the console, you'll see error messages.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [reported](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4189) this to angular team, and they say it is expected behaviour:

> This is expected behavior. The model can't stabilize because you are
>   changing the identity of the paginated array each time.
>
> It's better not to use a filter for this, and instead more the
>   functionality to a $scope.$watch in your controller.

So something like this cannot be done via filter, you'll have to perform pagination in controller, instead of using a filter.

Comment: Here is detailed explanation why it works this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12340772/411934

Answer (score -1):

I can't help you with your first question, but I can provide a solution to your problem.

I had a similar issue where I wanted to open and close a  every two elements and I fixed it with something like this:

```
myApp.filter('paginate', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory) {
    var arrayCache = $cacheFactory('paginate');
    return function(array, size) {
        if (!array) {
            return false;
        }
        var newArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            newArray.push(array.slice(i, i + size));
        }
        var arrayString = JSON.stringify(array),
            cachedParts = arrayCache.get(arrayString + size);
        if (JSON.stringify(cachedParts) === JSON.stringify(newArray)) {
            return cachedParts;
        }
        arrayCache.put(arrayString + size, newArray);
        return newArray;
    };
}]);
```

The way you would use this filter, is exactly how you have it in your template, passing the number of elements you want on each page.

About your second question: the best resources I have for Angular are all the videos on [egghead.io](http://egghead.io) and [A Better Way to Learn AngularJS](http://www.thinkster.io/pick/GtaQ0oMGIl/).

I've been also told that the book *Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS* is a great resource too.

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain why it works? Looks like the only difference is that you cache the result. You even do it after actual calculation.