# AngularJS InfDig error (infinite loop) with ng-repeat function that returns array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, infinite-loop, angularjs-infdig

Here's my code:

```
<h1 ng-repeat="item in func()">something</h1>

$scope.func = function(){
  return [{"property" : "value1"},{"property": "value2"}];
}
```

In Angular.js v. 1.1.1 there's no mistake. In Angular.JS v 1.2.1 I get an infDig mistake.

[Fiddle of v.1.1.1](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1502/)

[Fiddle of v.1.2.1](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1501/)

Could you explain this situation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Loop through items returned by a function with ng-repeat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 12):

> **As of AngularJS 1.2:** The "track by" expression was added to ng-repeat and more appropriately addresses this issue as demonstrated
>   in the following code.
>
> ```
> <h1 ng-repeat="item in func() track by $index">something</h1>
>
> $scope.func = function(){
>   return [{"property" : "value1"},{"property": "value2"}];
> }
> ```
>
> The following article helps understand the expression in more detail and why it is so useful, particularly when dealing with $$haskey [Using Track-By With ngRepeat In AngularJS 1.2 by Ben Nadal](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm).

The problem is that you're creating a new array each time, so it's something new that angular needs to track. As far as I can tell, `ng-repeat` runs, then immediately checks its collection again to see if anything changed in that cycle. Because the function returns a new array, that is perceived as a change.

**Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/kL5YZ/.**
If you look in the `console.log` and click the button, you will see that the `$$hashKey` property of the objects is being changed each time ng-repeat runs.

The change occurs starting at version 1.1.4, but the changelog doesn't give any clues as to why the behavior is different. The new behavior does make more sense to me.

Here's a great post I found explaining the current behavior in depth: [How to Loop through items returned by a function with ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat)

If you make sure to return the same object/array each time, you won't have the error. You could have the function cache anything it creates based on the arguments and always return the same array/object when those arguments are passed in. So, myFunc('foo') will always return the same array, not a new one that looks the same. See the notes in my code below. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/oZoHeRu/6/edit)**

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in foos">
  <div ng-repeat="bar in barFunc(foo)">{{bar.text}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="bar in barFunc('test')">{{bar.text}}</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.foos = [
    'a','b','c'
  ];
  //I put this into a service to avoid cluttering the controller
  $scope.barFunc = myService.getObj;
});

app.factory('myService', function() {
  /*
   * anything created will be stored in this cache object,
   * based on the arguments passed to `getObj`.
   * If you need multiple arguments, you could form them into a string,
   * and use that as the cache key
   * since there's only one argument here, I'll just use that
   */
  var cache = {};

  var myService = {
    getObj : function(val) {
      //if we haven't created an array with this argument before
      if (!cache[val]) {
        //create one and store it in the cache with that argument as the key
        cache[val] = [
          {text:val}
        ];
      }
      //return the cached array
      return cache[val];
    }
  };

  return myService;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I need to pass parameter to this function:
`<h1 ng-repeat="item in func(dynamicParameter)">something</h1>`

Comment: @user3162402 I updated my answer with a generic but complete solution. I have also found a really good post on SO about the way ng-repeat works with a function, but I still don't know why it used to work.