# AngularJS ng-repeat not showing values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple `ng-repeat` block that looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat = "Service in getServices()">
    {{Service}}
</div>
```

The corresponding controller defines `getServices()`

```
$scope.getServices = function(){
    try{
        var services = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.Store.Services.length; i++){
            services.push($rootScope.Store.Services[i].ServiceID);
        }
        console.log('services: ' + JSON.stringify(services))
        return services;

    }
    catch (err){
        console.log('no services')
        return [];
    }
};
```

For some reason, however, I am getting no Services in my view. I know I can just repeat directly over the `$rootScope` and that's how I had it before but this was an effort to debug. I am getting Services in my console:

`services: ["ATM","DELI","DIESEL"]`

Also, when I change the `getServices()` function to something like this:

```
$scope.getservices = function(){
  var test = ["a", "b", "c"];
  return test;
}
```

It does update the view correctly. Not sure what's going on! Note that I have many other perfectly working `ng-repeats` in the app.

**Solved**

I have no idea why but after removing [iscroll](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) from this particular page, it works fine -_-

Comment: Can you make a little fiddle demo?

Comment: can you try setting $scope.services directly to the array instead of using a function?  Then do the repeat with service in services?

Comment: @EugeneP Apply would cause an error, as an apply or digest is already in motion.

Also he is not updating the scope, so there is no need.

Comment: Omar, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat

Comment: @AndréSnedeHansen good point. missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that iScroll was the problem, have you checked there aren't any global variable collisions?

Maybe you should implement iScroll via Angular: http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-iScroll

Comment: Negative, getting the same result

Comment: @OmarMeky Can you supply a fiddle replicating the problem?

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: @OmarMeky Updated my answer again

Comment: I have noticed conflicts between [iscroll](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) and angularjs, adding data-iscroll tends to call angular functions twice among other bugs. I am not sure why this is; there are no global variable collisions I can see.