# Filtering total duplicates in object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I've created this filter:

```
app.filter('totalItems', function() { 

    return function (input) { 
        var total = [];
        input.forEach(function (value, key) {
            if (total.length > 0) {
                for (var i in total) {
                    if (input[key].descripcion == total[i].descripcion) { // 'descripcion' is an String
                        total[i].cantidad += 1; // 'cantidad' is a Number
                    } else {
                        total.push(input[key]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                total.push(input[key]);
            }   
        });
        return total; // It's returning just an empty array. Why?
    }
});
```

For this view:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Descripcion</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in tempCart | orderByPriority | totalItems">
    <td class="ar"> {{ value.descripcion }} </td>
    <td> {{ value.precio | currency: 'BsF.' }}</td>
    <td> {{ value.cantidad }} </td>
</tr>
```

Using this controller:

```
app.controller('cartController', ['$scope', '$firebase', function(sp, fb) {

    var userSessionRef = new Firebase('https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/development/user_sessions/uid/');
    sp.tempCart = fb(userSessionRef);
}]);
```

[(The reference looks like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAfYX.png)

The idea of the filter is to sum similar items and return an array with the total; if there are **three** objects that have 1 apple, the filter should return **one** object with 3 apples. But none of my tries have been successful.

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advanced.

**EDIT:**

[Thanks to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14683345/3366109), I've changed the filter for a simplest one:

```
app.filter('totalItems', function() {

    return function (input) { 

        var output = [],
        found,
        x = 0, 
        y = 0;

        for ( x = 0; x < input.length; x++ ) {
            found = undefined;
            for ( y = 0; y < output.length; y++ ) { 
                if ( input[x].id === output[y].id ) {   
                    output[y].cantidad += 1; // This line is causing a "$digest() iterations reached" error.
                    found = true;
                } 
            }
            if ( !found) {
                output.push( input[x] );
            }
        }
        return output;
    }    
});
```

The function works great but not the filter; it's producing this error:

> Error: $rootScope:infdig
>   Infinite $digest Loop

I haven't found a way to solve it even though I've read [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12340772/3366109)... Honestly, I don't know what could I do.

Comment: It looks like you're treating input as an object, but orderByPriority returns an array?

Comment: Apparently no, @Kato. I'm using almost the same code (without the `for..in`) in other filter and it's working well... I still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Is `.cantidad` defined for all inputs? In other words, does each and every input to your filter have a property defined on it called `cantidad` that has an integer value?

Comment: Of course. All elements in input have a `.cantidad` property and it's an integer value (I've verified few minutes ago to be 110% sure).