# angular orderBy multiple fields has syntax errors

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I am trying to use angular `orderBy` to order multiple fields, but i get syntax error as:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[ng-repeat='r in
>   vm.GetRequests() | filter: vm.SearchText |
>   orderBy:['LastName','FirstName']']

It seems there appears additional sign `']'`, but i do not have it in html

The html looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat="r in vm.GetRequests() | filter: vm.SearchText |orderBy:'RequestedOn'| orderBy:['LastName','FirstName']">
{{r.LastName}} : {{r.FirstName}}
</div>
```

the function `GetRequests()` returns a array of object as following:

```
[{FirstName:"Test1", LastName:"First"},{FirstName:"Test2",LastName:"Second"},{FirstName:"Test3",LastName:"Third"}]
```

Can anyone help me for the problem?

Changing HTM -  remove orderBy: 'RequestedOn'

```
<div ng-repeat="r in vm.GetRequests() | filter: vm.SearchText | orderBy:['LastName','FirstName']">
{{r.LastName}} : {{r.FirstName}}
</div>
```

but i still get syntax error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[ng-repeat='r in vm.GetRequests() | filter: vm.SearchText | orderBy:['LastName','FirstName']']
```

**UPDATE**

The syntax seems comes from a browserlink, because the order works goed when i get the error.
And recommend to put all order property in a array

Thanks a lot for the inputs all of you, especially thanks for RishiPrakash :)

Comment: try <div ng-repeat="r in vm.GetRequests() | filter: vm.SearchText | orderBy:['RequestedOn','LastName','FirstName']">

Comment: see, in the error it ,orderBy : RequestedOn is not present, error must be related to it.

Comment: @ Rishi Prakash - I remove the first orderBy: 'RequestedOn', but i still get this error : _Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[ng-repeat='r in vm.GetRequests() | filter: vm.SearchText | orderBy:['LastName','FirstName']']_

Comment: that last ] is actually end seniter of div[ng-repeat in error , atleast this riddle is solved

Comment: @ Rishi Prakash - i see now , the last ']' is the end of error tag, now i do not understand why i still get syntax error. I have already updated the HTML

Comment: I updated my answer, vm.SearchText() should be there not vm.SearchText.

Comment: @Rishi Prakash - I do not think so, because vm.SearchText is just a  string of ng-model, i have this HTML for filtering : _<input type="text" ng-model="vm.SearchText" />_, but even i remove |filter: vm.SearchText , i still get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67845/discussion-between-rishi-prakash-and-echo).

Comment: @RishiPrakash : Thanks a lot for your help , and it seems the problem comes from browserlink

Answer (score 0):

try `<div ng-repeat="r in vm.GetRequests() | filter: vm.SearchText() | orderBy:['RequestedOn','LastName','FirstName']">`

filter:vm.SearhText must be a function so () in end of it.

Comment: "RequestedOn" is also a property of the object, and it is a moment object. First i thought maybe the moment object can not be sorted, that is why i do not put it in the output array. But it is not the reason,i still get the same error

Comment: tell me the value of moment object?

Comment: @ Rishi Prakash - and another reason i put "RequestedOn" in a seperate orderBy is the array does not correct order for properties "LastName" and "FirstName" if i put "RequestedOn" also in the order array

Comment: these two object has following moment:1. _d: Mon Oct 27 2014 16:27:30 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"_i: "2014-10-27T16:27:30"_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: false_locale: Locale_pf: Object__proto__: Moment and  2. _d: Mon Oct 27 2014 10:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"_i: "2014-10-27T10:00:00"_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: false_locale: Locale_pf: Object__proto__: Moment

Comment: Ok, I have create the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/11581/ , can you create the case there?

Comment: @ Rishi Prakash - I know it is working in jsfiddle, I have tried it in Plunker based on the document for orderBy in AngularJS API.It is working fine, but i just do not understand why i get the syntact error

Answer (score 0):

I think that filter only works on arrays and doesn't evaluate functions. 
I would assign the request to a scope variable in the controller:
**js:**

```
$scope.requests = vm.GetRequests();
```

**html:**

```
<div ng-repeat="r in requests | filter: vm.SearchText | orderBy:['RequestedOn','LastName','FirstName']"> {{r.FirstName }}, {{r.LastName}} </div>
```

*note: I don't think there's a problem with the way you sort your array, although I prefer combining them in one orderBy expression as Rishi Prakash suggested.*

Comment: I do not have any problem if i have just one string ,like "orderBy: 'RequestedOn'", it is working for ordering based on  RequestedOn property, and it is also working if i use "orderBy: 'RequstedOn' | orderBy:'FirstName'". But it is not working if use array, like order:['RequestedOn','FirstName','LastName']--- as i said 'RequestedOn' is not the reason of syntax error

Comment: I said that the problem is with vm.GetRequests() not RequestedOn. orderBy expression is fine.

Comment: i use typescript and the generated javascript for function GetRequests() looks like: _ModelName.prototype.GetRequests = function() {...}_, i think this is the same as what you mean for $scope.requests = vm.GetRequests(), is it?

Comment: I meant that ng-repeat won't work right in the way you're doing, use a scope variable if you don't really need a function.

for more details see this post it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat