# How to use ngRepeat on element returned from a function (a filter, actually) - AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to use something like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='item in getShopItems(shop.id)'>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I have to use a function since I need the current element of the `ngRepeat` to apply the filter.

The `getShopItems(id)` function is as follows:

```
$scope.getShopItems = function(id){
  filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, {shop_id: shop_id});
  return filteredItems; 
}
```

Using `ngInit` can help but the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) discourages it.

If we cannot use functions for `ngRepeat`, how else should I apply the filter. Thanks in advance.

And here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/ugOZ7QgQ3EHVQUGWTCII [not working]

EDIT: `provider` and `shop` are the same

EDIT: I don't want to filter in view like `item in items | filter:{}`

Comment: Firstly, it will be better if you provided a plunker. Secondly you seems to provide already a solution to your question. I guess it does not work because of a know issue on looping on function result with ng-repeat : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat. But you should tell use about it.

Comment: I guess, you can use function within ng-repeat with interpolation - 
`<li ng-repeat='item in {{getShopItems(shop.id)}}'>{{item.name}}</li>`

Comment: U should do it like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14733332/1127787

Comment: How do you use `id` in `getShopItems`?

Comment: This is very useful page for how to use filters: http://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

Comment: So, how do I solve it? @LucDUZAN

Answer (score 2):

You could use filter as custom filter:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='item in items | filter:getShopItems'>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

and modify filter function a little:

```
$scope.getShopItems = function(item) {
  return item.provider_id == $scope.shop.id; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have two solution, either you init your array in your controller :

```
function getShopItems(id){
  filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, {provider_id: provider_id});
  return filteredItems; 
}

$scope.filterItems = getShopItems($scope.shop.id)
```

And for the views :

  {{item.name}}

But it is possible that this solution does not work in your case, for example if your id is suseptible to change.

A other way would be directly use your filter in the views :

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='item in items|filter:{"id":shop.id}'>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I would also recommand you to read this thread: [How to Loop through items returned by a function with ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat)

Comment: The problem I have with using ng-repeat in view is I need to know the length of the filtered array. Here's my problem.

stackoverflow.com/questions/31323790/unable-to-reference-filtered-array-in-ngrepeat-angularjs

The solution I got was to use the filter in controller.

Comment: You should definitly give us a punkler because in the code you provide us, I do not see why you can't use a filter in the views

Comment: Okay. Give me sometime. I'll make one

Comment: I cannot use filter in view because I later need the length of the filtered items in my controller. I tried using the `as` alias for `ngRepeat` but it didn't work.

Comment: For information, Stack overflow provide a plunker like features : https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I guess the as of ngRepeat does not work because it will put your value in a child scope of your controller. Just create a empty object on your controller and put your in this object on the view.