# Why is a function in ng-repeat called several times?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to supply a `ng-repeat` element by a controller function as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="picture in allPictures(data.pictures)"></div>
```

```js
$scope.allPictures = function(pictures) {
        alert("function called");
    //return... extract all pictures and return as array
}
```

Result: my `allPictures` function is called several times, even though I'd expect it to be called only once and then iterate over the results.

Why? And moreover: how can I prevent this and really call the method only once for picture supply?

Comment: ["...will execute multiple times in a single $digest cycle if a change is detected."](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: Call it in the controller, set returned value as a property on scope or controller and then `ng-repeat` _that_ instead.

Comment: try to avoid using functions for display in view due to digest cycles. Event handlers obviously are different

Comment: In no way. You must prepare data in controller. [Some info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would really avoid calling a function insides a ngRepeat attribute, since it will give errors and unexpected behaviour.

But to be honest I dont think that you would need to call a function inside a ngRepeat. I would suggest to do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="picture in allPictures"></div>
```

```js
$scope.getPictures = function(pictures) {
        alert("function called");
        //return... extract all pictures and return as array
};

$scope.allPictures = $scope.getPictures();
```

This way the `$scope.getPictures` function will get called and the `$scope.allPictures` will be created. ngRepeat can call that collection instead of a function.

See also my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ABr/w6kc8qyh/1/

Comment: in my case I am calling the function with a parameter from an outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

a little bit about the digest cycle:

we need to check every time something in the application changes - what was effected by that change, and re-evaluate all the places that might depend on that change,

so that is why the function in the ng-repeat was called multiple times - it had to check wheter the repeated list is the same after some changes happend in the application

read more about the digest cycle and two-way data binding:

http://blog.bguiz.com/post/60397801810/digest-cycles-in-single-page-apps/