# angular Infinite $digest Loop in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to call function in ng-repeat attribute, here is my code

[example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oSaMlhwXOkuMZJ2jaQCy?p=preview)

html

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat='item in getGroupedRange() track by item.id'>
    <span>{{item.val}}</span>
    <span>{{item.abs}}</span>
    <span>{{item.rel}}</span>
    <span>{{item.cum}}</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

js

```
$scope.getGroupedRange = function() {
    return [
      {
        val: 1,
        abs: 1,
        rel: 1,
        cum: 1,
        id: 123456
      }
    ];
  };
```

When I opened console I noticed the error

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: function (c,d,e,f){e=a(c,d,e,f);return b(e,c,d)}","newVal":9,"oldVal":8}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,d,e,f){e=a(c,d,e,f);return b(e,c,d)}","newVal":10,"oldVal":9}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,d,e,f){e=a(c,d,e,f);return b(e,c,d)}","newVal":11,"oldVal":10}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,d,e,f){e=a(c,d,e,f);return b(e,c,d)}","newVal":12,"oldVal":11}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,d,e,f){e=a(c,d,e,f);return b(e,c,d)}","newVal":13,"oldVal":12}]]
```

*The main goal of my code is using function in ng-repeat for calculating data in each event loop*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Loop through items returned by a function with ng-repeat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat)

Comment: @Tristan ```hashKey``` doesn't work from your link. so..

Comment: I believe that hashKey and track by are both related to how DOM rendering is handled (or not handled) for items in the repeat. The infinite digest issue is due to ngRepeat using $watchCollection internally which will pickup on the new object in your new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
  $scope.prev = null;
  $scope.getGroupedRange = function() {
    var data = [{
      val: 1,
      abs: 1,
      rel: 1,
      cum: 1,
      id: 123456
    }];
    if (angular.equals($scope.prev, data)) {
      return $scope.prev;
    }
    $scope.prev = data;
    return data;
  };
```

Comment: The discussion here was to explain you that using function in ng-repeat is a bad practice. But yes, you can always find a way shoot in your leg in angular world

Comment: @shershen Why do you think that using function in ng-repeat is a bad practice?

Comment: @shershen I do not think using ng-repeat on a function is bad practice at all. On the contrary, it's well aligned with functional programming. On the other hand, the discussion here shows how badly angular plays with FP.

Comment: how is mutating a member and returning it later functional? haha

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't use function in `ngRepeat` like this. The problem is that Angular uses strict comparison of objects in digest loop to determine if the value of the property changed since the last check. So what happens is that `getGroupedRange` returns **new** value (new array) each time it's called. Angular has no idea and considers this value as unstable and thus continues checking. But it aborts after 10 checks.

You need to construct necessary array and assign it to scope property, so it will not change during digest loop:

```
$scope.groupedRange = $scope.getGroupedRange();
```

then use it like in ngRepeat

```
  <div ng-repeat='item in groupedRange track by item.id'>
    <span>{{item.val}}</span>
    <span>{{item.abs}}</span>
    <span>{{item.rel}}</span>
    <span>{{item.cum}}</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: so using ```track by``` doesn't make sense?

Comment: Why, `track by` solves other problem it's not related to this one.

Comment: Sure I mean only my case.

Comment: how ng detemine that ```getGroupedRange``` returns new value?

Comment: It compares previos value (from the previous check) with new one. `getGroupedRange()` returns new array every time.

Comment: the comparison goes like this ```==``` ?

Comment: It uses strict `===`. But in any case `getGroupedRange() !== getGroupedRange()`.

Answer (score 0):

Angular will do calculation and automatic showing in template on data change for you. But by putting `ng-repeat='item in getGroupedRange()` you put this into endles cycle recalculation.

Try to avoid this by assigning the value of the items (that may be changed by `$scope.getGroupedRange` function in any way) in the list to some scope variable, say `$scope.range`, that will be iterated in `ng-repeat`.

in controller

```
$scope.getGroupedRange = function() {
    $scope.range =  [
      {
        val: 1,
        abs: 1,
        rel: 1,
        cum: 1,
        id: 123456
      }
    ];
  };
```

in template

```
 <div ng-repeat='item in range track by item.id'>
    <span>{{item.val}}</span>
    <span>{{item.abs}}</span>
    <span>{{item.rel}}</span>
    <span>{{item.cum}}</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: When I should call the getGroupedRange function? I don't want paste ```getGroupedRange()``` in each place... thx

Comment: you call it when you need,

Comment: I don't want to repeat myself.

Comment: you only need track by if you have similar items in the array. it doesn't infulence the other part that we are solving here.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div ng-init="grpRange = getGroupedRange()">
        <div ng-repeat='item in grpRange track by item.id'>
            <span>{{item.val}}</span>
            <span>{{item.abs}}</span>
            <span>{{item.rel}}</span>
            <span>{{item.cum}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```