# Angular infinite loop - $digest() and $watch() function

Tags: angularjs

I am understanding `$digest` and `$watch` functions. I found that whenever value of `model` changes then `angular` runs `$digest` again and if value of `model` changes very frequently then `angular` throws infinite loop error.

[Example from angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2239%22,%22oldVal%22:%2279%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2255%22,%22oldVal%22:%2239%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2295%22,%22oldVal%22:%2255%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2280%22,%22oldVal%22:%2295%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d,e,f)%7Be%3Da(c,d,e,f);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2220%22,%22oldVal%22:%2280%22%7D%5D%5D)

Ok then, this example throws `infinite error`

```
<div ng-repeat="user in getUsers()">{{ user.name }}</div>

...

 $scope.getUsers = function() {
    return [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];
  };
```

BUT this code does not throw any `infinite loop` error. Why is it so ? This example should also throw an error

```
 <div> {{getUsers()}}</div>

...

 $scope.getUsers = function() {
    return [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];
  };
```

because as per documentation `getUser` function anyways returning a new array everytime in both cases.

Thanks

Comment: @JenishRabadiya : My question is why second snippet is not throwing any error while the first code does.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using the ng-repeat directive. It has the potential to run thousands or hundreds of thousands of iterations, so an error is thrown even if you have only 2 items in the array.

Sort of a precaution.

Should be this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in getUsers()">{{ user.name }}</div>

...

var users = [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];

$scope.getUsers = function() {
    // Same array returned each iteration, no model changes.
    return users;
};
```

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33847397/178163  Basically, since you return a new array each iteration, angular thinks the model changed.