# AngularJS ng-repeat inside ng-repeat loop is goes infinite

Tags: angularjs

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="objective in objectives">
       <td>
          <p> {{objective.name}} </p>
          <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in getData(objective.id)">
              <td> {{data.value}} </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>

my controller code is ---

objectiveService.getObjective().success(function (data) {
    $scope.objectives = data;
    $scope.loading = false;
})
.error(function (data) {
    $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
    $scope.loading = false;
});


$scope.getData = function (id) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    var currentObjective = id;
    objectiveService.getObjectiveById(currentObjective).success(function (data) {


       $scope.loading = false;
       return data;

    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving Objective! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
        $scope.loading = false;

    });
};
```

i am working on AngularJS, above is my code which i am using, but this loop is going to infinite time and i don't understand where i did wrong, can anyone please help me

Comment: mind sharing the js code?

Comment: could u show your controller? What does the getData do?

Comment: i edited the question, pls check

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call an `$http` service inside `ng-repeat`, because it results in infinite loops. Explanation: [angular Infinite $digest Loop in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847336/angular-infinite-digest-loop-in-ng-repeat/33847397#33847397). Hope this helps.

You can call `$scope.getData()` for every `id` beforehand, store the results into an array, and then call this array in `ng-repeat`.