# AngularJS does not show JSON child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am facing an issue with angularJS, basically I trying to print the "img" child of below, but it does not print anything and does not even show an error. I have followed many tutorials of angularJS, but I am stuck at this point.
Any ideas on what's can be wrong ?

Here is the angularJS code :

```
    app.controller("Deals", function($scope){
    $scope.getDeal = function() {
    [
    {
        "name":"Joe"
        "img":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NsvH9ye1ycU/mqdefault.jpg"

    }];}    
});
```

Calling from HTML :

```
<ion-content ng-controller="Deals">
<h6>{{getDeal.img}}</h6>
</ion-content>
```

The result is blank; however I am willing to get the url of that image.

Comment: Are you attempting to print the raw json as a string or simply iterating through its contents and printing them?

Comment: Just iterating and print the "img" link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, when you're repeating, you need to call the getDeal() function in the ng-repeat. Here's an example,

https://jsbin.com/tavapuyaki/edit?html,js,output

```
<div ng-repeat="deal in getDeal()">
  {{deal.name}} <img ng-src="deal.img"/>
</div>
```

Also, your function is not returning anything. You need something like this:

```
$scope.getDeal = function() {
return [
{
    "name":"Joe",
    "img":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NsvH9ye1ycU/mqdefault.jpg"

}];
```

};

However, I would advise against doing that and creating a property that stores the contents of the array.

For instance,

```
$scope.deals = [{name:'myname', img: 'blah.jpg'}];
```

Here is another SO answer explaining as to why using a function is not advised in an ng-repeat. [How to Loop through items returned by a function with ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat)

Comment: Nice one ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be cause of square brackets. which means it needs  ng-repeat. try this it should work

```
<ion-content ng-controller="Deals">
<h6 ng-repeat="deal in getDeal">{{deal.img}}</h6>
</ion-content>
```

also remove quotes from keys of object. like this:

```
$scope.getDeal = 
    [{
        name: "Joe",
        img: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NsvH9ye1ycU/mqdefault.jpg"

    }];
```

check [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxjWWg)

Comment: If you remove the square brackets, it will not be an array anymore, and it will show an error. It does not work.

Comment: added codepen. u are doing something wrong for sure

Comment: It worked, but with removing " = function() " and I need that to pass variable in future...

Comment: It is perfectly valid to have quotes around key names.

Comment: Yeah it is, but i didnt find it useful in this particular case

Answer (score 0):

That is an Array which you are using, so when you use an Array you must use the array Index as Well.
So the correct Code Will Be

```
`<ion-content ng-controller="Deals">
<h6>{{getDeal[0].img}}</h6>
</ion-content>`
```

Comment: Did you remove the quotes in the Angular code for key ?