# AngularJS if/else in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

js i have this...

```
controller: "photogridCtrl",
templateUrl: 'js/ng-assets/templates/directives/photogrid-view.html',
scope: '=info'
```

in my controller i have 2.

```
$scope.home = [
    {
        img: 'img/burlington.jpg', 
        label: 'Burlington', 
        action: '#/', 
        row:'col-md-12', 
        class:''
    }
```

and the other one is...

```
$scope.featured = [
    {
        img: 'img/kitchener.jpg', 
        label: 'Kitchener', 
        action: '#/', 
        row:'col-md-12', 
        class:''
    }
```

in my view...

```
<div class="photo-grids">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='{{item.row}} margin-bottom' ng-repeat='item in home'>
        <a href="{{item.action}}" class="photo-item {{item.class}}" style="background-image:url({{item.img}});">
        <span class="photo-caption"><h4>{{item.label}}
        <br><small>Ontario</small></h4></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my main index i have 2 party of the page where i want to display the photogrid-view.html

```
<photogrid-view></photogrid-view>

<photogrid-view info='featured'></photogrid-view>
```

Now as you can see in my ng-repeat i have `"item in home"` I just want to ask how I can change `home` to something that will change depending on the variable in `<photogrid-view info='featured'></photogrid-view` so if it is featured it will output the values from `$scope.featured` and if the info=home then it will output the values from `$scope.home`. So it would be like...

If info=='home' then `ng-repeat="item in home"` else if info==''featured then `ng-repeat="item in featured"` sorry for the long explanation. But thanks! :)

Comment: if you use a isolated scope, you can use ng-repeat="item in info"
and set info from the outside like info before. 
<photgrid-view info='featured'></photgrid-view >
<photgrid-view  info='home'></photogrid-view>

Or is the controller the controller of the component/directive?

Comment: How will i get the value from <photgrid-view info='featured'> Info?

Comment: I haven't seen the syntax you are using before, but it seems you are using a directive. If you use scope: {info:'='} and <photo-grids info="myArray"> the value of $scope.myArray is automatically bound to the isolated scope of the directive.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.returnArray = function(){
    if($scope.info){
        return $scope.featured;
    }
    return $scope.home;
}
```

in view:

```
<div class='{{item.row}} margin-bottom' ng-repeat='item in returnArray()'>
```

or:

```
<div ng-init="entities = returnArray()"></div>
<div class='{{item.row}} margin-bottom' ng-repeat='item in entities'>
```

or just in view:

```
<div ng-show="info" class='{{item.row}} margin-bottom' ng-repeat='item in featured'>
<div ng-hide="info" class='{{item.row}} margin-bottom' ng-repeat='item in home'>
```

Comment: You cannot iterate over function using ngRepeat, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat). Also `ng-init` doesn't watch changes and as result list won't be updated. So first 3 examples are incorrect.

Comment: how will i get the value of info from <photogrid info='featured'>? if info == featured then return $scope.featured?

Comment: I'm sorry about the function, @KoIIIeY you're right, it doesn't work with raw values but for variables, it does the job.  By changes, I meant changing list.

Comment: @jeeeee , 'info' in your example is variable from scope, if you want (and really, you want :) ) you can remove second ng-repeat div, and ng-repeat use like <div ng-repeat="item in info"></div> Next in your view, <photogrid-view info='featured'></photogrid-view>, where 'featured' - array from scope, $scope.featured :)

Comment: and yep, I'm and Mikey forgot to close div tag :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-if="info === 'featured'" class='{{item.row}} margin-bottom' ng-repeat='item in featured'></div>
<div ng-if="info === 'home'" class='{{item.row}} margin-bottom' ng-repeat='item in home'></div>
```

This can be achieved easily with `ng-if`. In my opinion this is better than `ng-show` because this only appends it to the DOM if the condition is met, while `ng-show`just hides it.

Comment: i cant make it work witht his code sorry. :( But thanks! :)