# Execute method in one of ng-repeat child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github

I'm using angular's ng-repeat to populate table with data from GitHub api and I want one of the `<td>` to execute method that will return data. the problem is that this makes the function execute infinitely.

HTML:

```
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Languages</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos">
            <td>{{repo.name}}</td>
            <td></td> <!-- Get languages for each repo here. -->
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Angular:

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module("githubViewer", []);

  var MainController = function($scope, $http){

    var onUserComplete = function(response){
      $scope.user = response.data;
      $http.get($scope.user.repos_url)
          .then(onRepoComplete, onError);
    };

    var onRepoComplete = function(response){
      $scope.repos = response.data;
    };

    var onError = function(reson){
      $scope.error = "Could not fetch the data";
    };

    //search for user
    $scope.search = function(username){
      $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
          .then(onUserComplete, onError);
    };

    // These two execute infinately if executed in the ng-repeat's <td>
    $scope.findLangs = function(langsUrl){
      $http.get(langsUrl)
        .then(onLangComplete, onError);
    }

    var onLangComplete = function(response){
      return response.data;
    };

  };

  app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", MainController]);

})();
```

I've tried using {{ findLangs(repo.languages_url) }} in the `<td>` but it causes me to get this error:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

and appears to be infinitely executing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Loop through items returned by a function with ng-repeat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat)

Comment: That's not exactly what he's asking... it's a function _within_ the repeat, not the initialization of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use an expression there because you don't actually return a value from the `findLangs()` function. That said, I don't think that would cause an infinite loop. I think you'll need to actually grab the language data for each repo within the `onRepoComplete` callback, then just use that data in your template:

```
var onRepoComplete = function(response){
  $scope.repos = response.data;
  $scope.repos.forEach(function(repo) {
    $http.get(repo.languages_url)
      .then(function(response) {
        // change this to process the language data however you need to...
        repo.languages = JSON.stringify(response.data);
      },onError);
  });
};
```

Then in your template you can use the `languages` property of the repo:

```
<tr ng-repeat="repo in repos">
  <td>{{repo.name}}</td>
  <td>{{repo.languages}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I was already working on something working like that. Works like a charm, thank you.