# Can't get data from a function in a controller to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm new in AngularJS. I'm trying to create the dynamic table in a view:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Genre</td>
            <td>Duration</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="album in getAlbumsInfo(artists)">
            <td>{{ album.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ album.genre }}</td>
            <td>{{ album.duration }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my controller (`artists` received from the backend):

```
$scope.getAlbumsInfo = function (artists) {

    var albumsData = [];

    artists.forEach(function (artist) {

        var albumItemMap = new Map();

        albumItemMap.set("name", artist.name);
        albumItemMap.set("genre", artist.genre);
        albumItemMap.set("duration", artist.geduration);
        albumsData.push(albumItemMap);
    });

    return albumsData;
};
```

But it doesn't show any data in the table. Just simple table.
I've checked if I use the hard-code data from the `$scope` something like:

```
$scope.albums = [
    { name: 'Cali Roll', genre: 'Pop', duration: 45 },
    { name: 'Philly', genre: 'Rock', duration: 50 },
    { name: 'Rainbow', genre: 'Relax', duration: 55 }
];
```

and (part of view):

```
<tr ng-repeat="album in albums">
```

It works fine. But, in the case with the function `getAlbumsInfo` it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**: I need only one function, it's mandatory condition.

Comment: You haven't used `artists` in controller function. Why do you want that parameter?

Comment: Why are you calling `getAlbumsInfo(artists)` in ng-repeat ? what is `artists` object ?

Comment: Try `$scope.getAlbumsInfo(artists)`

Comment: Why you want use function in `ng-repeat`, You can call function in controller and use object here, Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat

Comment: @suzo yes, it's object

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Genre</td>
            <td>Duration</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="album in getAlbumsInfo()">
            <td>{{ album.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ album.genre }}</td>
            <td>{{ album.duration }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.getAlbumsInfo = function () {
  //call API and get artists and in success function add the code
      return API.getArtists().then(successfn);

    };

function successfn(response){
  albumsData = [];
  var artist = response.data;

        artists.forEach(function (artist) {

            var albumItemMap = new Map();

            albumItemMap.set("name", artist.name);
            albumItemMap.set("genre", artist.genre);
            albumItemMap.set("duration", artist.geduration);
            albumsData.push(albumItemMap);
        });

return albumsData;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `getAlbumsInfo` from the ng-repeat each time, generate the `albums` array in your controller and then repeat it in the view. Call the `getAlbumsInfo` function with the `artists` object when you get it from backend as shown below :

```
$scope.albums = $scope.getAlbumsInfo(artists);
```

Now as we have `albums` array, repeat it in your html :

```
<tr ng-repeat="album in albums">
        <td>{{ album.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ album.genre }}</td>
        <td>{{ album.duration }}</td>
 </tr>
```